# How to hide os.system output on windows with python

Tags: python, windows

Guys how can I hide the output of this code in python on windows?

```
os.system(r"C:\Users\john\Desktop\chrome.exe")
```

This starts Chrome but I get some error messages ("Nothing significantly affecting") what I need is to hide these errors, how can I do this?

Comment: When you have some problems related with function, you should look into docs. In 90% of cases with built-in functions, possible solutions will be there. [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system)

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system("ls > .out && rm -rf .out")
```

A simple brute force solution can be to redirect the output to temp file and delete that file. ( tested on Linux)

You can try to do the same in windows the commands may be a little different

Comment: You can redirect to `/dev/null`

Comment: I'm using windows, not Linux

Comment: @Dkns, well, there's no `ls` in Windows. But anyway, in Windows you can redirect to `NUL`

Comment: @Dkns, `dir > NUL`

Comment: @Olvin Roght Is something like this? `>C:\Users\John 2>&1?`

Comment: @Dkns, `2>&1` redirecting stderr to stdout. Solution for your problem I provided in first comment under question. `os.system()` doesn't fit your requirements, you should choose another function.